# Django, не работает функция login()

Tags: django

Стандартная авторизация из документации Джанго,но в строке с вызовом функции login() выходит ошибка

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

view.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def auth(request):
    login = request.POST.get("login", "")
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")

    user = authenticate(username=login, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            print('disabled account')
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        print('invalid login')
```

Функция authenticate() срабатывает нормально, юзер есть. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4):

У вас `login` — это строка, которая устанавливается вот тут:

```
login = request.POST.get("login", "")
```

Строку нельзя вызывать как функцию. А джанговая функция `login`, которую вы импортировали в начале файла, стала недоступна, потому что вместо неё вы создали строковую переменную `login` в этой самой строчке.

Переименуйте вашу строку `login` в, например, `username`, и всё будет норм